# Doctrine OneToOne relationship doesn't load from inversed side

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a user. Some users use a messaging system. Those users (but not all) have messageUserSettings. I want to create a "OneToOne" relationship between these entities.

This is what I have (edited down):

**MessageUserSettings.php**

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * MessageUserSettings
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="message_user_settings")
 */
class MessageUserSettings {

    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="messageSettings")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * Get user
     * @return User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

}
```

**User.php**

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Users
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(
 *      name="users",
 *      uniqueConstraints={
 *          @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="users_username_unique", columns={"username"}),
 *          @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="users_email_unique", columns={"email"})
 *      }
 * )
 */
class User {

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="MessageUserSettings", mappedBy="user")
     **/
    protected $messageSettings;

    /**
     * @return MessageUserSettings
     */
    public function getMessageSettings()
    {
        return $this->messageSettings;
    }

}
```

I can see the foreign key and fields in the table as expected.

```
TABLE_NAME             COLUMN_NAME  CONSTRAINT_NAME      REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME  REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
message_user_settings  user_id      FK_4C6502BDA76ED395  users                  id
```

I can go from `MessageUserSettings` to `User` but not the other way around. What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

For a One-To-One, Bidirectional:

```
class MessageUserSettings 
{

    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="messageSettings")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
     protected $user;

     /***/
}
```

Comment: `JoinColumn` is automatically applied like that (based on names) anyway, however even with that line it still doesn't work.

Comment: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: "The above @JoinColumn is optional as it would default to address_id and id anyways. You can omit it and let it use the defaults."